# UIButton does not have a member named setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: ios, swift

I am using xcode 7 beta 2 and getting the following error.  How can I solve it?

> UIButton does not have a member named setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

```
for char in keys {
        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
        btn.setTitle(char, forState: .Normal)
        btn.sizeToFit()
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        btn.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: (216/360.0), saturation: 0.1, brightness: 0.81, alpha: 1)//
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: .Normal)

        btn.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)
        btn.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)

        btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleBtnPress:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(btn)
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is a (boolean) property
of `UIView`. In Objective-C, you can use the "dot syntax" *or* the
setter method to assign a value to the property

```
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[btn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

but in Swift you just assign a new value to the property:

```
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```